# Why are objects in the same SKNode layer not interacting with each other?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have less than 1 year using SpriteKit so I didn't use SKNodes as layers before until recently.

I have an SKNode layer that holds all of the fish and the user's position, for example:

```
var layerMainGame = SKNode()
layerMainGame.zPosition = 50
layerMainGame.addChild(userPosition)
layerMainGame.addChild(pipFish)
addChild(layerMainGame)
```

The interaction whether the user touched a fish or not is handled with this function, which is basically checking if their frames crossed:

```
if CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRectInset(node.frame, delta.dx, delta.dy), self.userPosition.frame) {
    print("You got hit by \(name).")
    gameOver()
}
```

It works. The interaction between the userPosition and pipFish works. What doesn't work is fish that are added as the game progresses. I have a function spawning different types of fish in intervals like this:

```
func spawnNew(fish: SKSpriteNode) {
    layerMainGame.addChild(fish)
}
```

The interaction between the user and those fish that get added to the same layer later in the game does not work. I can pass right through them and no game over happens. When I completely remove the entire layerMainGame variable and just add them to the scene like normal, all the interactions work. Adding them all to the same SKNode layer doesn't work.

This is the function that creates a hit collision for every fish.

```
func createHitCollisionFor(name: String, GameOver gameOver: String!, delta: (dx: CGFloat, dy: CGFloat), index: Int = -1) {
    enumerateChildNodesWithName(name) { [unowned me = self] node, _ in
        if CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRectInset(node.frame, delta.dx, delta.dy), self.userPosition.frame) {
            me.gameOverImage.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: gameOver)
            didGetHitActions()
            me.runAction(audio.playSound(hit)!)
            if index != -1 {
                me.trophySet.encounterTrophy.didEncounter[index] = true
            }
            print("You got hit by \(name).")
        }
    }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
createHitCollisionFor("GoldPiranha", GameOver: model.gameOverImage["Gold"], delta: (dx: 50, dy: 50), index: 1)
```

It works when the fish are not in the layer, but doesn't work when they are added to the layer.

Comment: Are you setting the layerMainGame's size and position to match your scene? Maybe you need to translate the rect of the fish to be in the coordinate system of the scene?

Comment: I didn't have any of that before but I did just test it out and no difference.

Comment: Do you have any properties set on your layerMainGame that are also being applied to its children (your fish) like `dynamic = false` that would affect their behavior?

Comment: Nope; there is nothing is applied to the layer besides being added to the scene and it's z rotation since I'm not using SKPhysics at all.

Comment: If your are not using physics, how do you detect collisions? Or what you mean by *interaction*?

Comment: The reason I'm not using SKPhysics was because I created this game when I was a beginner and had no knowledge of SKPhysics. I use CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRectInset()) which works fine when the fish are not in the same layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a node is placed in the node tree, its position property places it within a coordinate system provided by its parent.

Sprite Kit uses a coordinate orientation that starts from the bottom left corner of the screen (0, 0), and the x and y values increase as you move up and to the right.

- For **SKScene**, the default value of the origin – `anchorPoint` is (0, 0), which corresponds to the lower-left corner of the view’s frame rectangle. To change it to center you can specify (0.5, 0.5)
- For **SKNode**, the coordinate system origin is defined by its `anchorPoint` which by default is (0.5, 0.5) which is center of the node.

In your project you have `layerMainGame` added for example to the scene, his anchorPoint is by default (0.5,0.5) so the origin for the children like your fish is the center, you can see it if you change the fish positions like:

```
func spawnNew(fish: SKSpriteNode) {
    layerMainGame.addChild(fish)
    fish.position = CGPointZero // position 0,0 = parent center 
}
```

Hope it help to understand how to solve your issue.

---

**Update**: (after your changes to the main question)

To help you better understand what happens I will give an example right away:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        var layerMainGame = SKNode()
        addChild(layerMainGame)

        let pipFish = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellowColor(), size: CGSizeMake(50,50))
        pipFish.name = "son"
        self.addChild(pipFish)

        let layerPipFish = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellowColor(), size: CGSizeMake(50,50))
        layerPipFish.name = "son"
        layerMainGame.addChild(layerPipFish)

        enumerateChildNodesWithName("son") { [unowned me = self] node, _ in
            print(node)
        }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Now I will simply change the line:

```
layerMainGame.addChild(layerPipFish)
```

with:

```
self.addChild(layerPipFish)
```

**Output**:

[image]

**What happened?**

As you can see [enumerateChildNodesWithName](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483024-enumeratechildnodeswithname?language=objc) written as your and my code print only childs directly added to `self` (because actually we launch `enumerateChildNodesWithName` which it is equal to launch `self.enumerateChildNodesWithName` )

**How can I search in the full node tree?**

If you have a node named "GoldPiranha" then [you can search through all descendants](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode#1654468) by putting a // before the name. So you would search for "//GoldPiranha":

```
enumerateChildNodesWithName("//GoldPiranha") { [unowned me = self] ...
```

Comment: Insightful, but it doesn't explain why no collision is called when the objects intersect over and over. The fish spawn from the right side of the screen and move left. The user is a small rectangle. I could drag the rectangle across the entire image of the fish back and forth and no collision is called despite the sprites intersecting multiple times. That also doesn't explain why the first fish I add to the layer is the only one I'm able to touch and not the others.

Comment: Have you try to make some breakpoint to your intersection function? If you spawn the first fish and it collide with your user, than all the other fishes must collide with it. I'm pretty sure there must be some mistake when you pass the "second" (and so the others) fish to the function to check intersections with user but there is not enough code in your question: please add some code so I can help you also with intersections.I await your further information.

Comment: Well the collision code works perfect when I don't add the fish to the layer. They all use the same generic function for each fish. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem! All I had to do was call enumerateChildNodesWithName on layerMainGame instead of self like I originally had it.