# children's children with enumerateChildNodes(withName:using:)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sknode

does `enumerateChildNodes(withName:using:)` go through and search the children of children, and their children, etc?

Or does it just search the first generation of children?

Docs are here, and mention nothing about this: https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483024-enumeratechildnodes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That function is called on the parent to search it's children and that's it. It does not search the children of children. You would have to call that function on the children to search it's children.

I've ran into issues with this before when I didn't know why a certain node with a name was not being found. It's because I had that node I was looking for was a child of another child.

This [Link to my Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113789/why-are-objects-in-the-same-sknode-layer-not-interacting-with-each-other) on why my node was not interacting with a certain node was because the node I wanted was not being found with enumerateChildNodes and I finally realized it at the very bottom in a comment.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!!! I deeply appreciate the explanation and answer. For me, this is exactly the behaviour I was hoping it would have... because it means there's a "name space" for the first generation, which is super helpful to what I'm doing.